# cassandra jdbc serach ( how to exclude where condition value is null)

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

i'm using datatstax jdbc driver.
and i want to execute lookup query like this.

```
Statement statement = new SimpleStatement("select * from tablename where condition1 = ? and condition2 = ?", value1, value2 );
```

condition1 is partition key.
and condition2 is part of primary key.

here is my problem.
'value2' can be null. **and If 'value2' is null, I want to exclude it from the search condition**

Do I have to make two queries per case?
like this?
or **is there any way to handle null values?**

```
Statement statement = new SimpleStatement("select * from tablename where condition1 = ? , value1 );
```

Comment: I'd just create two statements and pick one based on the condition.

Comment: creating 2 statements on base of column 'condition2' will be the best approach.